# how can I make the code read different files?

Tags: c++

how can I make the code read different  files

```
infile.open("C:\\Users\\kujak\\Desktop\\simmac1\\job_1.txt");
```

like i want to read job_1 then job_2 and on

Comment: use a `std::string` to generate the filename in your loop.

Comment: Hold however many files you need to read in an `std::string str[]`, then iterate on them and read each one.

Comment: What do you feel is wrong with adding a line like the following to your code: `infile.open("C:\\Users\\kujak\\Desktop\\simmac1\\job_2.txt");`? (There are several potential reasons, but your question lacks the contextual details needed to determine which reasons apply to your case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to do, but the simple way is the one suggested by @drescherjm which is store it in a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
for(int i=0;i<loop_control;i++) {
    std::string path = "My/Path/job_" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
    ifstream infile(path);

    //...

}
```

Something like that should work.